# Override method syntax ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to override a method in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method like this

```
cell.customSwitch {
    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
    {
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
        NSLog(@"customSwitch touchesended");
    }

};
```

however this isn't working (I'm normally a Java guy :P). Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of similarities between Objective-C and Java, but that's not one of 'em. ;-)

If you want to create a cell with a customized `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` method, you'll need to declare and define that class separately. Something like:

```
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell
{
//...
}
@end

@implementation MyCell
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"customSwitch touchesended");
}
@end
```

Once you've done that, you can use MyCell in your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: @mikez Why do you need to override the touch handling in 9 different places? It seems like you're trying to solve your problem with the wrong solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however it is not UITableViewCell, but a CFCustomSwitch (UICustomSwitch). Since I'll need to make 9 unique overrides of this method throughout the app, I'd prefer to find another way to capture the touch events of this switch.Heres my method so far (pastebin.com/5Ybm7S0Z),but I need to basically change the boolean values and save them every time this switch is selected. I implemented the tag method, and my intention was to update the booelans based on the tag returned. i.e. if (tag == 1) {boolean_one = !boolean_one;}. How could I do this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Hollance I have 9 distinct UITableViews that all need to assign values to different boolean variables to be stored in NSUserDefaults. Overriding the touch handling is just a means to store the unique data.

Comment: How about this: you use the standard target-action mechanism whereby the switch sends a message to your view controller when it is tapped and the controller sets the appropriate boolean in NSUserDefaults. If you're overriding methods in a standard UI control class, you're probably doing it wrong, no matter what you're actually doing. The standard mechanism for dealing with controls is target-action, so just use that unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Comment: @mikez, I'm not familiar with UICustomSwitch, but if it's a control the usual thing to do would be to set an appropriate target and action. With good MVC design, you don't need a separate control for each value that you want to set -- you just connect standard controls to different actions in the controller. Subclassing may be appropriate if you want a switch that draws itself differently or has some different behavior (e.g. a switch with 3 positions instead of 2), but in this case it sounds like the standard behavior is all you need.

Comment: @Hollance @Caleb When viewing the outlets of the CustomSwitch in Interface Builder, I see one that says "Value Changed" among others such as Touch Up Inside, etc. Should I connect these to the UIResponder? If so, where do I go from there? Thanks!

Comment: @mikez, please read [*The Target-Action Mechanism*](http://tinyurl.com/5vyrv9y) for complete information on this topic. In a nutshell, though, you should add an IBAction method to your view controller to handle the switch's change in state. Then connect the switch's Value Changed event to the action you just created in the view controller -- ctrl-drag a line from the Value Changed circle to your view controller, and then choose your action.